# EmberJS 2.3 link-to issues

Tags: ember.js

I am using Ember.js 2.3. I have a {{link-to}} that works on parts of the app and not other parts. Here is the {{link-to}}

```
    {{#link-to 'leads'}}Leads{{/link-to}}
```

On the parts that it does not work, the link is still generated. If I inspect the element, I see:

```
    <a id="ember397" href="/leads" class="ember-view">Leads</a>
```

However, the link is not clickable by the browser. Could it be connected to the {{outlet}}? The link that works is modifying the {{outlet}} and the link that isn't working is in the template generated inside the outlet.

I am new to Ember and not sure of the terminology or if I am asking it correctly.

Comment: That's hard to believe. Can you create demo on ember-twiddle.com or emberjs.jsbin.com?

Comment: Yep, I will go create one right now

Comment: You are right Daniel. Something else is going on with that page. I was able to add a link elsewhere and have it work. Thanks for pointing me to ember-twiddle.com or emberjs.jsbin.com. Those are really cool tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is something else going on in my code that is causing that page to not have links work.